# Add carriage return after Ctrl+C

Tags: 11.10, command-line

When I kill a process in the terminal using ctrl+c no carriage return is inserted.

I have no idea if I changed a setting inadvertently or what happened. I'm running 11.10.

How can I change the settings so that a carriage return is added after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

Having `igncr` set in the [stty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stty.1.html) settings would make your terminal ignore carriage returns (and pressing return would have no effect), although hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would still reload the prompt on a new line. To temporarily reset your tty, run

```
stty sane
```

and see below for how to put this command in a file so it is executed each time the terminal is loaded, even though the defaults should already be very similar.

**However**, even though you mention carriage return, I think you simply mean that `^C` isn't being inserted after you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

This happens when the `-echoctl` option of stty is set: see the full list of options at [the Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stty.1.html) for stty. When a `-` is appended before an option, the opposite result occurs- i.e. ctrl is not echoed to the terminal. To see what non-standard options you have, just enter `stty` and see if `-echoctl` is listed:

```
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?;
ixany iutf8
-echoctl
```

To temporarily change the setting, so that `^C` is echoed when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you can run:

```
stty echoctl
```

However, to set it 'permanently', you can either place `stty echoctl` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` or perhaps, as noted [here](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?127575-Saving-stty-settings-permanently-with-automatic-read.-..&s=2dc3bbdc6fcdce857de6dbc6d6ff81f4), you can create a `.stty` file in your home folder and place the following in your `bashrc`:

```
stty $(cat ~/.stty)
```

Any other customisations can go in `.stty` as well, say, for example, if you wanted to reassign the stty shortcuts and have different ones from the default values.