# How to reset bash keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

How can I reset the bash shell's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keyboard shortcut? I changed it a few months ago and can't seem to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut used to cancel processes in the terminal is **not** a bash shortcut, but relates to the tty, as it is a shortcut for one of the signals (SIGINT in this case) that can be sent to processes which are active in the terminal. As noted [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766004/why-linux-always-output-c-upon-pressing-of-ctrlc) by [Wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser),

> It is the terminal (driver) that intercepts the ^C and translates it to a signal sent to the attached process (which is the shell).

For more on how SIGINT and other POSIX signals are handled, see [this in depth article](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html).

As a note, Bash shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to move to the beginning of the line) and others are managed by the readline library; current bindings can be shown by `bind -P`; see `man bash` and `man readline`, or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/readline.3readline.html). However, even if you also had <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> set using readline or in your `.inputrc`, the tty set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would still override it.

**However**, you should check whether you have changed any keyboard shortcuts in `gnome terminal`. Go to the menu and click edit > keyboard shortcuts as if you have made one of those <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that would override the tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

To check [current tty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stty.1.html) bindings run `stty -a`, which lists, for example,

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
```

In order to clear the current binding for the interrupt signal (intr), first run:

`stty intr ^-` and only then run `stty intr ^C` to reassign the shortcut.

Make sure you use an upper case C, as this is very important. This is the way to reset the shortcut, but if this still doesn't work you may need to put `stty intr ^C` in a file and have it read at startup of the terminal, as I discuss [in a related answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146401/add-carriage-return-after-ctrlc/215357#215357).

More general information about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is available in these two Stackoverflow articles:

- [why-linux-always-output-c-upon-pressing-of-ctrlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766004/why-linux-always-output-c-upon-pressing-of-ctrlc)
- [how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process)

Answer (score 0):

To reassign the interrupt signal (or [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29#SIGINT)), call the [`stty`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty) command along with the proper mapping arguments:

```
stty intr ^c
```

Source:

- [Oreilly's ***Unix Power Tools***](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003302.do) - 5.8. Setting Your Erase, Kill, and Interrupt Characters

Comment: I tried this solution but it wasn't helpful. The Ctrl+C keyboard shortcut in the terminal that kill process unavailable because I changed it .
How can I return it back to his original purpose?

Comment: oh ok, i misunderstood the question. editing to address your issue.